# отправка папки через socket

Tags: java

Eсть у кого нибудь готовый код для отправки содержимого папки через socket ?

Comment: Чем вас не устраивают примеры, которые выдает гугль по запросу "java file socket"?

Comment: мне нужно отправить содержимое папки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас есть два способа:

1. Создать архив и отправить его.
2. Открыть директорию, пройтись по всем файлам и отправить их индивидуально.

Второй пример в действии:

Клиент:

```
File[] files = new File(directory).listFiles();

Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hostDomain), port);

BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

dos.writeInt(files.length);

for (File file : files) {
    long fileLength = file.length();
    dos.writeLong(fileLength);

    String fileName = file.getName();
    dos.writeUTF(fileName);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    int theByte = 0;
    while ((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) {
        bos.write(theByte);
    }

    bis.close();
}

dos.close();
```

Сервер:

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

int filesCount = dis.readInt();
File[] files = new File[filesCount];

for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
    long fileLength = dis.readLong();
    String fileName = dis.readUTF();

    files[i] = new File(dirPath + "/" + fileName);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(files[i]);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    for(int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) bos.write(bis.read());

    bos.close();
}

dis.close();
```

[Источник кода](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420250/how-to-send-a-list-of-files-over-a-socket-in-java)

Comment: сервер мне выдаёт ошибку строки 26 это String fileName = dis.readUTF(); почему ?

Comment: @as1andrey1, какую конкретно ошибку он вам пишет?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
 at aaa.aba.main(aba.java:26)

Comment: в знаете решение проблемы ?

Comment: @as1andrey1, он выдаёт вам исключение конца файла. Также хочу обратить ваше внимание, что в документации написано: DataStream обнаруживает состояние конца файла, ловя исключение конца файла вместо проверки на неверное возвращаемое значение.