# Как можно отослать все файлы из указанной папки?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, подскажите как можно отослать все файлы на сервер из указанной папки без реализации выбора файла (грубо говоря, сказать программе название папки и всё что там есть нужно отправить на сервер) ?
Примечание: вопрос как отправить реализован, осталось от куда забирать файлы.

Comment: забрать все файлы из папки и по одному отослать?

Comment: потрудитесь объяснить, что же именно у вас не реализовано?

Comment: @metalurgus забрать все файлы из папки и отослать всё содержимое

Comment: И что же именно из этого огромного вопроса у вас не получается? Вы не знаете, из какой папки забирать файлы? Вы не можете их прочитать? Не знаете, как получить список файлов в папке? Не знаете, как отправить файл на сервер? Не знаете, как запустить цикл для отправки последовательно всех файлов?

Comment: @metalurgus Не знаю, как получить список файлов в папке? Не знаю, как запустить цикл для отправки последовательно всех файлов?

Comment: Почему же вы тогда не задаете ваши вопросы? Клещами их из вас тянуть, что ли?

Comment: Вопрос ваще не ясен. Может вам лучше использовать не папку, а архив и отсылать его? Корректность данных обеспечено.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [отправка папки через socket](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495679/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-socket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Не знаю, как получить список файлов в папке?

Получить cписок файлов из папки:

```
File folder = new File("путь к вашей папке");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); // получить массив всех файлов в папке
```

> Не знаю, как запустить цикл для отправки последовательно всех файлов?

Цикл для отправки:

```
for(File f : listOfFiles ) {
    sendFile(f); //отправка файлов из списка поочередно. 
}
```